# What does "for" mean in "the solution is for there to be fewer banks"

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions

This context comes from an article written on Mar 27, 2009
on the business insider website by Joe Weisenthal

> "Some have argued that this is what we need in banking. Nassim Taleb, for one, has argued that banks should just be like utilities -- simple, regulated and boring. That's fine, but utilities all have local monopolies and with little incentive to serve customers. So there'd be one or maybe two NYC retail banks, with little incentive to overlap geographically or do much of anything to improve the customer experience. That's what banks-as-utilities means, and perhaps that's what Krugman would like to see.
>
> Along these lines, John Hempton argued today that the solution is **for** there to be fewer banks -- contrary to the argument that we need new banks -- with a cozy, profitable oligopoly, with little built-in incentive for crazy risk-taking.

I would like to provide some research but I honestly can't even guess what this word might mean in this context.

Comment: ***For** a solution, consider "fewer banks"* Compare *It's a good idea **for you to** go = It's a good idea **that you [should]** go*.

Comment: I think the answers should give you a pretty good idea that **for** doesn't have a specific meaning by itself: you can probably see that if you just leave out the word!  But it's grammatically used to connect the two parts of the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

> *the solution is* [*for there to be fewer banks*]

"For" has no meaning in this example.

It's simply a clause subordinator introducing the infinitival clause "for there to be fewer banks".

This use of "for" occurs when the infinitival clause has a subject -- in this case the subject is "there".

Comment: Importantly, "there" is the subject of "to be"; if you make it a finite sentence, you get: "There are fewer banks." (This is sometimes called a "dummy subject.")

Comment: @alphabet I said in my answer that "there" is the subject of the infinitival clause.

Answer (score -2):

[Merriam Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/for)
a
—**used as a function word to indicate purpose**
a grant for studying medicine

- Along these lines, John Hempton argued today that **the purpose** of a solution is [for there to be] fewer banks.

is the same as:

- Along these lines, John Hempton argued today that the solution is *for there to be* fewer banks --

Comment: Those aren't the same at all. "A solution is for there to be fewer banks" might be a response to "our bank regulators are overworked and going on strike." On the other hand, increasing taxes on banks so that they will go out of business is a solution for the purpose of there being fewer banks.

Comment: The lemmings have arrived. for = for the purpose of.